# phpstorm добавить пустую строку в шаблон нового файла

Tags: phpstorm, settings

как в phpStorm добавить пустую строку в шаблон нового файла, чтобы новый файл имел всегда пустую строку, а курсор стоял над ней, это нужно для github, иначе он добавляет "красную стрелочку" когда смотришь pr - за которую меня ругают. Я а постоянно забываю добавить пустую строку в конец файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings/Preferences | Editor | General -> Ensure line feed at file end on Save
(похоже что это для всех типов файлов)

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm понимает `.editorconfig` - http://editorconfig.org/
Или плагин ему какой-то для этого нужен.
Там есть `insert_final_newline`.